# Ignite on-heap cache access by computejobs increasing server heap

Tags: caching, heap-memory, ignite

we have 2 server nodes and 1 client node and a replicated cache .

When the client submits multiple compute jobs , cache access [get()] from these jobs are increasing the server heap . I am thinking that each access [get()] is creating a new object in the JVM heap . The more compute jobs we run in parallel , the more memory is needed .

Since our use case is a read-only cache , Is there a way to re-use the same cache object across different compute jobs ?

Answer (score 1):

By default Ignite stores data in binary form only and deserializes a value each time it is read. In read-only scenario you can change this behavior by forcing Ignite to save deserialized value as well:

```
<property name="copyOnRead" value="false"/>
```

Note this will increase initial memory consumption as each entry will have both serialized and deserialized value. However, new object will NOT be created on each `get()`.

Comment: Thanks Val for the reply . I have made the changes to the config to disable 'copyOnRead' , but i still see that the server memory increases during compute job execution. Please note that our design involves multiple compute jobs with lower granularity , rather than big compute jobs . Our server nodes die after executing 3 Million compute jobs .

Comment: Is there an issue associated with that? Memory will be used during the load of course, and then the garbage will be collected - that's how Java works.

Comment: on the same topic , when i have 'copyOnRead' = false , i expect  to see the deserialized object when i am profiling the server node with jvisualvm . But i am not seeing our domain objects , all that i see is a byte[] with huge memory.

Comment: Can you please help me find the issue here , below is my configuration for the cache . `  CacheConfiguration<String, CacheMapDOWrapper> cacheMapCacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<String, CacheMapDOWrapper>();
  cacheMapCacheCfg.setCacheStoreFactory(FactoryBuilder
    .factoryOf(CacheMapCacheStore.class));
  cacheMapCacheCfg.setIndexedTypes(String.class, CacheMapDOWrapper.class);
  cacheMapCacheCfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED);
  cacheMapCacheCfg.setName(CacheNames.CACHE_MAP_CACHE);
  cacheMapCacheCfg.setCopyOnRead(false);`

Comment: Binary form of an object is always saved in cache. With `copyOnRead=false` Ignite will also cache the deserialized value on first read.

Comment: Thanks Val for the answer. If i am loading a cache that is of 5GB partitioned across 5 servers , and there is no other cache in the server . I expect to see approx 1 GB (max 2 GB) of memory (heap) on these servers  . But i see about 4GB memory in each instance (with copyonread = false)

Comment: a byte[] for 1.5 GB , GridDhtAtomicCacheEnty for 0.6 GB , ConcurrentSkipListMap$Node for 0.5 GB , BinaryObjectImpl for 0.5GB ,GridH2KeyValueRowOnheap for 0.5 GB are some of the big consumers of memory on the server node

Comment: These objects are all used to store data and indexes. As I said before, it doesn't look like you have an issue in the first place. Ignite does introduce memory overhead, it's required to provide scalability, performance and other features.